# Select certain number child or children selector withing parent. css

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to select a certain number of child selectors? For example

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-a">abc</div>
  <div class="child-b">def</div>
  <div class="child-c">ghi</div>
  <div class="child-d">jkl</div>
  <div class="child-e">mno</div>
  <div class="child-f">pqr</div>
  <div class="child-g">stu</div>
</div>
```

How can I select just `.child-a, .child-b, .child-c` ?

Or just select `.child-d .child-e, .child-f` ?

Can it be done with :nth-child pseudo-classes like

```
  div.parent div:nth-child(1,2,3) { margin: 15px 0 0 0; display:inline }
  div.parent div:nth-child(4,5,6) { margin: 30px 0 0 0; display:inline }
```

?
something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if the `div`s have those classes, you can simply list them:

```
.child-a, .child-b, .child-c
```

If you want to do it with `nth-child`, you must list them like this:

```
.parent :nth-child(1), .parent :nth-child(2), .parent :nth-child(3)
```

Comment: No problem - sometimes a sanity check is all that's needed.

Comment: At the rate I'm going with my mod-ish edits, you'll have your bronze [css-selectors] badge in no time.